# SQL Bulk Insert Error because Last Field Contains Carriage Returns

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert, carriage-return

thanks in advance for your help.

I am trying to import a flat file into my SQL server database. I am getting truncation errors. The problem I'm having (I think) is the last field of the file is a free form text field which appears to allow carriage returns within the field. So I end up having {CR}{LF} as a Row Terminator, but sometimes the {CR}{LF} is really just a new line within the free form text in the last field.

Does anyone have any idea how to load this data in? Thanks for your help.

Here's my code:

```
DROP TABLE   #SHELL
CREATE TABLE #SHELL
(
Field1 varchar(50)
,Field2 varchar(50)
,Field3 varchar(50)
,Field4 varchar(50)
,Field5 varchar(50)
,Field6 varchar(160)
,Field7 varchar(50)
,Field8 varchar(50)
,COMMENTS nvarchar(MAX)
 )

BULK INSERT #SHELL
FROM 
'[thefilepath].txt'
WITH
(
FIRSTROW = 1,
FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

Here's a picture of the table as viewed in Notepad++ so you can see the carriage returns and line feeds.

[Table Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNOEm.png)

Comment: You are trying to use a process that will not likely work reliably.  I basically agree with chezy525.  Bulk Insert handles very very very few data issues.  Basically it rejects the data if it is not clean.  To use Bulk Insert, You generally have to run a filter/clean up program first.  I for example write/run a python or perl script.  Reading line by line fixing any previously resolved errors.  This fixes the data then you can load it in with Bulk Insert.  Also consider using a more powerful text editor like UltraEdit or one that handle hexadecimal so you can see the data issues accurately

Answer (score 1):

Your image didn't come through, but when the export or file came from a LINUX system often you need to use HEX. Try this:

```
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',FIRSTROW=1,ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a')
```

Comment: Sorry, the system won't let me paste images in so you have to click on the link. "Table Sample" is a hyperlink to the image.

Comment: Well, not really. I think @onupdatecascade has the right idea about processing the text with a scripting language - but that's a little over my head. So I might need to ask around and see if I know anyone who can help me out there.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be deliberate about it, I'd pre-process the text file to remove those "mid field" line terminators, or, if they are important to keep, substitute another escape character for them.

For example, create a script that takes each line in the file and attempts to split it on the column delimiter, and compare how many tokens you get back - to determine if a line is really a complete line with all expected columns.

For any line that has fewer tokens than expected, merge it with the previous line, optionally inserting your escape character into that last column.

Write the results out to a new file, so every DB record is truly one line.

After import, optionally, use an update statement to put the line terminators back into that last field. Example, if you replaced them with, say, a | then update to replace | with \n in SQL.

Example: "records" in the file might be:

```
value value1 value2 some long text
wraps to another line and
yet another line
value value1 value2 a better behaved record on one line
```

That's two records, but four lines. In preprocessing the file, make it:

```
value value1 value2 some long text|wraps to another line and|yet another line
value value1 value2 a better behaved record on one line
```

Then the records are actually one per line in the file, and every CRLF is the end of a line AND the end of a record. Bulk import works, but the value of the last column will be

```
some long text|wraps to another line and|yet another line
```

Perform an update replacing | by CRLF in SQL to return to an accurate representation of what was in the file

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like the right approach. But I honestly have no idea how to go about doing that. Python?

I don't understand why you would need to put the line terminators back into the last field once it is in SQL. When you merge a line with the previous line do you lose the 2nd (later) line's row terminator? If so, wouldn't I still have the same problem trying to bulk insert?

Comment: Personally I like PowerShell, but any scripting language that can process the text would work

Answer (score 0):

Bulk insert alone can't really handle this. So, there are two options:

1. Pre-process the file so that each record is only on a single line.  Basically, you'll need to replace each mid-field CRLF with some other character/string.
2. Load the file into a temp table of a single data column and then use SQL to combine the mid-field CRLF and eventually get to your final table.  NOTE: SQL is generally really bad at this (splitting strings, etc), you can use some libraries to help, but personally, I'd try to avoid this solution.